# How to connect to remote database on Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Probably been covered but I keep getting *"connecting to the Wordpress database"* which isn't what I'm after. In a nutshell I have a perfectly fine Wordpress site, I also have a MySQL database on another server which has some data I'm after. The code works fine on phpfiddle *(is this the standard?)* but whenever I try to use it on the Wordpress site, either with shortcodes or in the header.php it keeps hanging, throwing errors and won't connect to the DB, any ideas why?

**Edit:** To make things clearer, it's a meteorological database I want to connect to in order to pull things like Temperature from. Nothing native or related to Wordpress.

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("ip","user","pass","db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Gives me this

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on...
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be looking at the WordPress WPDB class - https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

For example:

```
<?php 
$wpdb_dbconnect = new wpdb(user, pass, db_name, localhost);
$wpdb_dbconnect->show_errors();
$object = $wpdb_dbconnect->get_results("SELECT * FROM table_name");
foreach ($object as $person) {
    echo $person->name . ', ';
}
?>
```

Comment: Still no luck. Do I have to use the WPDB class? If so does it have to go somewhere specific? The header.php, functions.php etc? It would be great if I could just use mysqli functions.

Comment: You can use it directly in your templates or wrap it in a function within functions.php. This is how you would connect to external DB from within a WP environment.

Answer (score -3):

To connect to a second (and third, and forth...) database, I recommend [HyperDB](http://wordpress.org/plugins/hyperdb/) plugin.

Comment: The question explicitly said it wasn't the wordpress database they want to connect to. It is a second database from inside a WP app.

Comment: Your answer now consists of (mostly) the old answer (to the wrong question) and now has a [link only answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) to the actual question.